# Java OpenGL: Render all pixels to a buffered image and draw to screen?

Tags: java, opengl, render, lwjgl, bufferedimage

I'd like to be able to render all my game items pixels to a `BufferedImage` in openGL and simply add it to a list of `BufferedImage` called images. Then in my game loop, I simply loop through each `BufferedImage` and draw it to the screen. However, I have tried looking around and I can't find anywhere that explains how to do this. I'm not new to Java, but relatively new to OpenGL and have been following tutorials for the past few weeks. `ThinMatrix Java LWJGL game development` is the set of tutorials I have been following. I have emailed the guy personally, but I have had no reply and that was a few weeks ago.

This is currently what I have to attempt to render a `BufferedImage`:

```
private static void renderImage(BufferedImage image){
    int[] pixels = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];
    image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels, 0, image.getWidth());

    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() * 3); //4 for RGBA, 3 for RGB

    for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++){
            int pixel = pixels[y * image.getWidth() + x];
            buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF));     // Red component
            buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));      // Green component
            buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF));               // Blue component
            buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF));    // Alpha component. Only for RGBA
        }
    }

    buffer.flip(); //FOR THE LOVE OF GOD DO NOT FORGET THIS

    // You now have a ByteBuffer filled with the color data of each pixel.
    // Now just create a texture ID and bind it. Then you can load it using 
    // whatever OpenGL method you want, for example:
    GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA8, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
}
```

Then in the main loop:

```
        for (BufferedImage image : imagesToRender){
            renderImage(image);
        }
```

What I'd like to achieve is when I call `world.render(camera)`, it creates a `BufferedImage` and adds it to the list of images in the main class. The GUI will also do this, but on a separate image. Then after calling the GUI and world render methods, it loops through the list of images as above and renders them to the screen. The reason is obviously efficiency. If I can render it to a `BufferedImage` before drawing it to the screen, I can render it to a small `BufferedImage` then scale it up to fit the screen, reducing render cost.

My issue is that I don't know how I would go about drawing all my textures and objects and terrain stuff to a 2D `BufferedImage` that can be drawn to the screen.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT 1:

Link to source code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxW4fcuviUOccnpwVG5qZG9qR2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding here, but the reason people generally use OpenGL is because rendering on the CPU is slow. But you want to render on the CPU and then send the bufferedimage to OpenGL? What you are doing right now is uploading bufferedimages to OpenGL in a loop, not rendering them (that would be the next step). Have you followed the tutorial from start to finish?

Comment: @HenkDeBoer Yes i've followed from the start to the finish, however in his Dev log for his Sucawun engine, he explains in one of the videos how he renders everything "off-screen" as a 2D image, then draws it to the frame. I have done this before following The Cherno's game programming tutorials in 2D, but he converted everything to pixels arrays then formed a buffered image from that, and the final result was scaled up to the frame size. Thus optimizing performance. I wanted to know if it was possible/worth doing it with openGL

Comment: No not at all, the performance gain by the downsampling is nothing compared to the performance lost by drawing on the CPU and by the need to transfer all the pixels to your graphics card. If you want a solid performance boost, consider switching to OpenGL for all your drawing. If you don't want to do that, switching only the final texture-to-screen operations will not gain you much, if anything.